# Compile cupy only for selected GPU architecture

Tags: python, opencv, gpu, cupy

Looking into git repository (https://github.com/cupy/cupy) and documentation (https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/install.html) I've no found any method for generating an executable only related to the current hardware (GPU).

For making an example, in `opencv` (in order to reduce by a huge factor the compilation time that can be more than 8h in the old environment), you can specify the architecture of the GPU. (here an example for compile `opencv` from a source related to the hardware only)

>
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/DEVOPS/SDK/jvm/jdk-11.0.4/ ; cmake3 ..  -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON  -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON  -D WITH_CUDA=ON  -D WITH_GTK=ON  -D WITH_OPENGL=ON  -D ENABLE_CXX11=ON  -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON  -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/opt/SP/packages/opencv_contrib/modules  -D BUILD_opencv_java=ON  -D BUILD_opencv_python2=ON  -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON  -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=ON  ***-D CUDA_GENERATION="Maxwell"***  -D WITH_OPENMP=ON  -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF  -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON  -D BUILD_TIFF=ON   -D WITH_OPENCL=ON  -D WITH_IPP=ON  -D WITH_TBB=ON  -D WITH_EIGEN=ON  -D WITH_V4L=ON  -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF  -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF  -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE  -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)")  -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3)  -D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print(get_python_inc())")  -D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())")  -D PYTHON3_LIBRARY=/opt/DEVOPS/SDK/anaconda3/lib  -D OPENCV_PYTHON3_INSTALL_PATH=/opt/DEVOPS/SDK/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages  -D PYTHON3_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=/opt/DEVOPS/SDK/anaconda3/bin/python  -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON

By this way, the code will be generated only for the given architecture.

I've found this useful commit.
(https://github.com/cupy/cupy/commit/4d3b05c4f010d62f9daf92a049fa2e8a789f6cc2)

Have someone tried to compile Cupy only for the given architecture forcing '--generate-code' parameter to '*--generate-code=arch=compute_**XX**,code=compute_**XX***' instead of use all possibile arch as default?

[default compilation arch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQpch.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CUPY_NVCC_GENERATE_CODE` environment variable is available in v7.0.0b2 or later. https://github.com/cupy/cupy/pull/2293
You can use e.g. `export CUPY_NVCC_GENERATE_CODE="arch=compute_50,code=sm_50"` to build CuPy that only runs on the specified hardware.